# Nginx PHP Page downloads instead of displaying

Tags: php, nginx, download

This has been a struggle for the past two days. I've done a lot of searching, couldn't find anything to fix it.

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
 user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
            worker_connections 768;
            # multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

            ##
            # Basic Settings
            ##

            sendfile on;
            tcp_nopush on;
            tcp_nodelay on;
            keepalive_timeout 65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;
            # server_tokens off;

            # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
            # server_name_in_redirect off;

            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type application/octet-stream;

            ##
            # Logging Settings
            ##

            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

            ##
            # Gzip Settings
            ##

            gzip on;
            gzip_disable "msie6";

            # gzip_vary on;
            # gzip_proxied any;
            # gzip_comp_level 6;
            # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
            # gzip_http_version 1.1;
            # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

            ##
            # Virtual Host Configs
            ##

            include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
            include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

Here's my default file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name [redacted server IP];

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ /admin/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }


}
```

The page is stored in /usr/share/nginx/html/admin/index.php -- it prompts for the username/password (which works fine), but as soon as I login, it downloads instead of showing the php webpage.

If I put the 'location ~ /admin/' block after the 'location ~ .php$' block, it works, but doesn't authenticate.

There are scripts I wrote in another folder that work fine when called 'in the folder /usr/share/nginx/html/api/XXX.php' (which inserts stuff into the MySQL database), but it just returns JSON stuff.

**You are awesome for helping me out, I really do appreciate it.**

Comment: uncomment that 1 line and it will work.

Comment: @r3wt I tried that, no luck. I'll change the code in the post to show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are commenting the `php5-fpm` sock, delete the comment from the following line:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Change your admin path configuration to use the php5-fpm sock:

```
location ~ /admin/.+\.php$ {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
 }
```

OR move your admin configuration path AFTER the `~\.php$ {}` rule
(both worked for me)

make sure the php5-fpm service is running and you've restarted nginx

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart && sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: No luck, I un-commented that line, saved, and ran your commands (getting as a response: 

php5-fpm stop/waiting 

php5-fpm start/running, process 20506


 * Restarting nginx nginx

) What do you mean by 'make sure the file exist in this path'?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the access.log/error.log? `tail /var/log/nginx/error.log` || `tail /var/log/nginx/access.log`

Comment: I opened the error log, accessed the page (having it download), then ran the error log again and noticed nothing added. I did the same for the access log and it looks fine (I just have a page now that only has <?php phpinfo() ?> -- to rule out any problems with php code)

Comment: what about the access.log? is there anything there?

Comment: (thank you for your help this far, really) I access the page and see "[my IP] - [my htaccess username] [03/Dec/2014:21:27:29 +0000] "GET /admin/phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"

Comment: the nginx configuration is configured good so far, how are you accessing your local enviorment? try to set up a virtualhost edit your hosts file `sudo nano /etc/hosts` add a line to the hosts file `127.0.0.1 local.test.com`. change the `server_name [redacted server IP];` to `server_name local.test.com;`; restart your nginx service `sudo service nginx restart`. and try to access your website using this url: `local.test.com`. let me know if it works.

Comment: also make sure your php file name is `index.php`

Comment: Unfortunately this is a remote server, I'm ssh-ing in. And I have an index.php file with a bunch of code in it, as well as a 'phpinfo.php' file in the same directory, so I can rule out something being wrong with the 'index.php' code by testing with the 'phpinfo.php' (that just has <?php phpinfo() ?>)

Comment: It works. Wow. Just. Wow. You = da man. Do you have a BTC address?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the default PHP block into your conf.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
    }

   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Without this block the expected behavior is to show the file. You need to have PHP FPM running and configured to make this work. Instructions are available at http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample

Comment: I tried this (commented out the location block and inserted this one into the /sites-enabled/default file), but no luck. I'm 94% sure my PHP FPM is running and configured -- do you know how I would check this? EDIT: also, this renders the /api/XXX.php files useless, so I had to revert to what I had originally

Comment: To check if php-fpm is running `service php5-fpm status`. If php-fpm is configured to listen to a port, you can check the corrent port and ip with `netstat -ntaup |grep php`. If this does not return anything, php-fpm is listening to unix socket. To check this run `ls /var/run/php*sock`.

Comment: Service is running: 'php5-fpm start/running, process 20506'. Running "sudo netstat -ntaup | grep php" doesn't return anything (this is a remote server). Doing the 'ls /var/run/php*sock' gets the return: "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"

Comment: Also, I tried following the nginx.org link you sent me to the letter, but still no luck. And I'm trying every time incognito mode, to avoid a cookie problem